# Unable to get response in string from weburl?

Tags: android, web-services, httpurlconnection

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = "";
            for (String url : urls) {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                    InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += s;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           // textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));
            Log.i("NNNNNNNNNNNNNN", ""+Html.fromHtml(result));
        }
    }
```

URL:http://demo.ftheline.com/restaurant/soma-eats/app-order?order_id=710&amount=3&discount_amount=0&discount_code_id=0&restaurant_name=soma-eats&payment_method_nonce=fake-valid-visa-nonce

Response:

```
{
    "error": 0,
    "message": "Success",
    "url": "http://demo.ftheline.com/restaurant/soma-eats/thank-you/710"
}
```

How can I get data as `String` from given url? I have tried above code and getting `HTML` error response? Please Help

Comment: BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i have tried above code and getting html error which are in view source from my domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this using below way.

I use below way in my application for get response from weburi.

Have a look :

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

String responseString = null;
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = "";
            try {
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                StatusLine statusLine = execute.getStatusLine();
                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                }else {
                    //Closes the connection.
                    execute.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return responseString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(result!= null){
                // textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));
                Log.i("NNNNNNNNNNNNNN", ""+Html.fromHtml(result));
            }   
        }
}
```

Comment: i have used this code but getting error page as we got b4 your task. every time i got the error. can you plz give me another code or help me on this. i have tried many code of them but not cant fix it

Comment: I am getting view source from my domain like below url
view-source:http://demo.ftheline.com/